# Is there a way to list the properties of an indexing catalog?

Tags: c#, properties, indexing

I wanted to get list of properties for an Microsoft indexing catalog. Is there a way? If yes how can it be done..?

I use C# 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the Indexing Service stores the properties in the registry, so unfortunately the best way to enumerate them is to query the registry. The relevant keys can be found here:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ContentIndex
```

If you know the names for the properties you are interested in, you are probably better off using the [AdminIndexServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691558.aspx) COM object to query those values through the [GetLongProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691548.aspx) and [GetSZProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691593.aspx) methods (found in ciodm.dll, which was in C:\WINDOWS\System32 on my computer).

See this reference for more complete info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692084(VS.85).aspx